# Error in using local geoJSON file for adding it on my MapBox GL JS API

Tags: jquery, json, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a geoJSON file with 7000 features in my local path. Using it in my ASP.NET MVC View(HTML page) for rendering it on the map. I'm reading the geoJSON file using the jQuery $.getJSON function. When I check it in my console, I find that data is read. But when I add it in the add source map box function I get multiple errors stating Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object and style is not done loading.

Code for reading and adding it in the MapboxAPI

```
    $("document").ready(function () {
        var datare = $.getJSON("/geojson/SDM769198.geojson", function () {
            console.log("success");
        })
            .done(function () {
                console.log("second success");
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log("error");

            })
            .always(function () {
                console.log("complete")
            });

        console.log(datare);
        map.on('load', function () {
            
            map.addSource('vicdata', {
                'type': 'geojson',
                'data': datare
            });
        });
```

Console output
JSON response

[image]

Console Error
[image]

Any advice on how I can load my local data into Mapbox API?

I tried multiple ways of uploading the geoJSON file to GitHub repo and using them as a link as referred in the documentation, still no luck.

Comment: I can see that there is an error saying "Input data is not a valid Geojson object". Please check and validate your json using https://geojsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error:

> Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object

is that your input data is not a valid GeoJSON object.

You can use geojsonlint.com to detect such errors and get hints on how to fix them.

Comment: It's a valid JSON file.

I tried it using D3 library as used in this https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-update-feature/  documentation. It worked :)

Comment: Valid JSON, maybe, but not valid GeoJSON.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the getJSON the wrong way.

When you `var datare = $.getJSON...` datare is not the actual json but an object representing a AJAX request.
Later, when you console.log(datare), what chrome does is interpret the data as you expand it ... hard to explain but anyway your code should be

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    map.on('load', function () {
        $.getJSON("/geojson/SDM769198.geojson", function (j) { // j is the actual json
            map.addSource('vicdata', {
                'type': 'geojson',
                'data': j
            });
        });
    });
});
```